# How do I uncheck a radiogroup after a certain button is selected?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have a radiogroup where each radiobutton changes text after I press the "submit" button. Each button corresponds to a score. But after I press "submit" the radio button that was previously selected is staying selected on the next screen when the radio button text changes. How do I unselect the radiogroup completely? I assume that I add the java code to my action listener part of my code?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public int score = 0; //answer score
public int PreviousScore;
int i = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final  TextView Score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button); //button


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    question1(); //call params for question

    //button listener, when button clicked, produce output on textfield "Score"
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PreviousScore = score;

                Score.setText(String.valueOf(action()));

                i++;
                question1();

        }

    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void question1(){
if(i>3){
    findViewById(R.id.Score).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
    t.setText("Final Score");
    Button AnswerA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AnswerA);
    AnswerA.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Button AnswerB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AnswerB);
    AnswerB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Button AnswerC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AnswerC);
    AnswerC.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Button AnswerD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AnswerD);
    AnswerD.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
    else {
    findViewById(R.id.Score).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
    TextView A = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerA);
    TextView B = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerB);
    TextView C = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerC);
    TextView D = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerD);



    t.setText(question[i]);
    A.setText(answerA[i]);
    B.setText(answerB[i]);
    C.setText(answerC[i]);
    D.setText(answerD[i]);
}
}


public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    if(i<2) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.AnswerA:
                if (checked)
                    score = PreviousScore + 2;
                break;
            case R.id.AnswerB:
                if (checked)
                    score = PreviousScore + 4;
                break;
            case R.id.AnswerC:
                if (checked)
                    score = PreviousScore + 6;
                break;
            case R.id.AnswerD:
                if (checked)
                    score = PreviousScore + 8;
                break;
        }
    }

    else if(i>=2)
        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.AnswerA:
            if (checked)
                score = PreviousScore + 1;
                break;
        case R.id.AnswerB:
            if (checked)
                score = PreviousScore + 2;
                break;
        case R.id.AnswerC:
            if (checked)
                score = PreviousScore + 3;
            break;
        case R.id.AnswerD:
            if (checked)
                score = PreviousScore + 4;
            break;
    }

}

public String action(){

    String action = null;
    if (score <= 11)
        action= "Low Risk";
    else if(score < 15)
        action = "Medium Risk";
    else if(score > 15)
        action = "High Risk";

    return action;
}
```

}

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/Score"
    android:text="score goes here"
    android:layout_above="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/AnswerA"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/AnswerB"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AnswerA"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/AnswerC"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AnswerB"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/AnswerD"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AnswerC"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

From `RadioGroup` documentation, you need to call `clearCheck()`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#clearCheck()

Comment: I am getting "cannot resolve method" error on "clearCheck"

Screenshot: http://imgur.com/o1pEU0j

Comment: You are casting it to a button rather a radio group. Change your 2 lines as follow: `((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup).clearCheck();`